# C# equivalent of Lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying to convert some JS into C# and i got to this piece but cant figure out what a C# equivalent would be. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction?

I just need help with the contents of these two functions. The $iterator is coded in another spot but im guessing that the C# version of the following code doesnt need it. If you need me to add it, i can.

The context these functions are being called is:

```
var centers = Lambda.array(Lambda.map(this.hexes,function(hex) {
            return me.hexToCenter(hex);
        }));
```

And the functions are:

```
var Lambda = function() { }
Lambda.array = function(it) {
    var a = new Array();
    var $it0 = $iterator(it)();
    while( $it0.hasNext() ) {
        var i = $it0.next();
        a.push(i);
    }
    return a;
}
Lambda.map = function(it,f) {
    var l = new List();
    var $it0 = $iterator(it)();
    while( $it0.hasNext() ) {
        var x = $it0.next();
        l.add(f(x));
    }
    return l;
}
```

Comment: Lambdas are so ubiquitous with C# and LINQ that a quick Google search should give you literally hundreds of relevant examples.

Comment: See [Lambda Expressions (C# Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) (lambda's and delegates can be closures). Of course you can't add expando properties, but [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) provides most everyday operations: e.g. filter (Where), map (Select), reduce (Aggregate) and new [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) can be added over IEnumerable<T> as required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't really need your own `map` and `array` methods. There is already the same functionality available, you just have to add `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file and you'll be able to use both `Select`, which is a projection method and `ToArray` which created an array from your collection. They are both extension methods set on `IEnumerable<T>`, so you can use them on almost any collection.

```
var centers = hexes.Select(x => me.hexToCenter(x)).ToArray();
```

is an equivalent of you JavaScript code:

```
var centers = Lambda.array(Lambda.map(this.hexes,function(hex) {
            return me.hexToCenter(hex);
        }));
```

Comment: Ahh awesome, thanks! I knew it would be with Linq but wasnt sure what to use with it. Thanks again!

Comment: Mungoid if your question is answered (it is :) you should mark it as selected

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a fairly simple C# lambda:

```
var centers = this.hexes.Select(hex => me.hexToCenter(hex)).ToList();
```

`Select` and `ToList` extension methods are provided by LINQ - you need to add `using System.Linq` to use them.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to go the [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) route here.

Your `map` is equivalent to LINQ's `Select`, e.g.

```
var centers = this.hexes.Select(hex => me.hexToCenter(hex)).ToArray();
```

The expression `hex => me.hexToCenter(hex)` is a lambda expression in C#, which `Select` uses to project `this.hexes` into your desired form.

`ToArray()` is equivalent to your `Lambda.array` call.

[101 LINQ Samples in C#](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) is a great resource for examples on using LINQ.

**note** most of the 101 samples use the *query* syntax as opposed to the *functional* syntax I've used above. They are roughly equivalent for simple cases, but being comfortable with the *functional* syntax shouldn't be a problem for you, coming from JS background.